# How to edit attribute table with decimal numbers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, editing

I have been adding points to a vector layer and I want to define their value in a specific column. When I try to edit the values, that are in decimal numbers, it only allows me to type integers.

How do I edit points in my attribute table in decimal numbers?

This is before(Z_COORDS) and after(ZCOORD) I tried to edit the column. 
[image]

Comment: What is the problematic field definition?

Comment: Field definition? Sorry, I am new to QGIS.

Comment: @JGH open up the layer properties of the mower2shapefile layer, check the FIELDS section, and let us know what the data type of the ZCOORD field is... it might be a SMALLINT, which doesn't store decimals...

Comment: @JGH Under "Type" it says: qlonglong. And type name: Integer64.

Comment: I selected New Field to add another column. However, when I click 'Type', I do not see the 'Decimal Number (real)' option. I attached a screenshot[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlO7j.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlO7j.png) I have version 3.12.2 and my professor has version 3.12.1, so it appears for him but not me. Also as you can see there is no 'Length' or 'Precision' options to fill in. I do not know what to do. What is the best thing to select instead? Or should I download version 3.1.12 instead and continue working using that version of QGIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The field you are editing must accept decimals. You can add a new field of type `real`. The length is the total number of numbers and the precision is the number of numbers after the decimal. So length 2 precision 1 will let you save 0.0,  9.9 but not 0.01 nor 10

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the field did accept decimals until i edited it. But now I haven't been able to recreate my problem, your solution works!

Answer (score 1):

you can modify the label decimal numbers as shown in  the figure
[image]